# WHERE != not working as intended in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently running this code:

```
select distinct day 
from v_nem_rm16, dbp_holiday 
where v_nem_rm16.day != dbp_holiday.holiday_date;
```

Why am I still getting results where `v_nem_rm16.day` IS equal to `dbp_holidays.holiday_day`? I want to filter out any rows where the date in `v_nem_rm16.day` is equal to the dates in `dbp_holidays.holiday_day`.

Comment: Where one date is equal to **the dates** in [...]? Don't you see a problem with that? How can one date be **equal to** multiple dates? Your code followed your thinking; the thinking was wrong, not the code. What you should look for is dates that are "not in" [...] Then write the code to follow that line of thinking. `where ... NOT IN (select holiday_date from dbp_holiday)` should give you what you need. (By the way is it `holiday_date` or `holiday_day`? Be consistent.)

Comment: What does this have to do with PL/SQL? What you wrote is a SQL statement (a SELECT query), not PL/SQL code.

Comment: @mathguy Thank you! The cleared things up for me and gave me exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Queries that retrieve the requested data are already supplied by other posts. 
But you also asked:

> Why am I still getting results where v_nem_rm16.day IS equal to dbp_holidays.holiday_day?

Assume that your  `dbp_holidays` table  contains at least two different dates:

```
table: dbp_holidays

holiday_day
----------
2015-05-01
2015-07-31
2015-12-25
```

table `v_nem_rm16` contains dates that may  or may not coincide with a date from `dbp_holidays`, e.g.

```
table: v_nem_rm16

day
----------
2015-02-17
2015-12-25
```

The cross join

```
select
    v_nem_rm16.day
    dbp_holidays.holiday_day
from    
    v_nem_rm16,
    dbp_holidays
```

retrieves the following tuples

```
day         holiday_day
----------  ----------
2015-02-17  2015-05-01
2015-02-17  2015-07-31
2015-02-17  2015-12-25
2015-12-25  2015-05-01
2015-12-25  2015-07-31
2015-12-25  2015-12-25
```

so each row  from the  `v_nem_rm16` table appears n-times, where n is the number of rows of   `dbp_holidays`.

Adding the where-clause may remove at most one of each `v_nem_rm16.day` value and there are at least n-1 rows for each `v_nem_rm16.day` date remaining.

So

```
select
    v_nem_rm16.day
    dbp_holidays.holiday_day
from    
    v_nem_rm16,
    dbp_holidays
where   
    v_nem_rm16.day != dbp_holidays.holiday_day
```

retrieves

```
day         holiday_day
----------  ----------
2015-02-17  2015-05-01
2015-02-17  2015-07-31
2015-02-17  2015-12-25
2015-12-25  2015-05-01
2015-12-25  2015-07-31
```

And reducing the select list to

```
select
    v_nem_rm16.day
from    
    v_nem_rm16,
    dbp_holidays
where   
    v_nem_rm16.day != dbp_holidays.holiday_day
```

gives

```
day
----------
2015-02-17
2015-02-17
2015-02-17
2015-12-25
2015-12-25
```

After applying the distinct operator

```
select
    distinct v_nem_rm16.day
from    
    v_nem_rm16,
    dbp_holidays
where   
    v_nem_rm16.day != dbp_holidays.holiday_day
```

we get

```
day
----------
2015-02-17
2015-12-25
```

So **all** days of the `v_nem_rm16` table are returned by the select.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `not exists`?

```
select r.day 
from v_nem_rm16 r
where not exists (select 1
                  from dbp_holiday h
                  where r.day = h.holiday_date
                 );
```

You can do what you want with a `JOIN`, specifically a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select r.day 
from v_nem_rm16 r left join
     dbp_holiday h
     on r.day = h.holiday_date
where h.holiday_date is null;
```

This just emphasizes why you should never use commas in the `from` clause and always use explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: How does this show that you never should use commas instead of the join syntax?

Comment: @miracle173 . . . You don't understand the query.  The `NULL` value appears because there is  no match between the tables.  You should review your outer joins.